# belongsTo in Cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, belongs-to

I'm following CakePHP naming convention

I need to make "many to one"-$belongsTo association 
Citie to Countrie       ------- meaning Many Cities belong to a Country

This is the Citie Model

```
class Citie extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Citie';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Countrie' => array(
            'className' => 'Countrie',
            'foreignKey' => 'countrie_id'
        )
    ); 
}
```

You can see that there are no association data when result is returned on this link
[DisplayCity](http://carevikuli.com/vordol/diskoteki/cake/app/cities)

This is the Countrie Model

```
class Countrie extends AppModel 
{
    var $name = 'Countrie';
}
```

Here you can see that I follow the naming convention. [Display all countries](http://carevikuli.com/vordol/diskoteki/cake/app/countries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are following the convention
so you must have City model for cities table, Country model for countries table and the foreignKey will be country_id

```
<?php
class City extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'City';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        )
    );
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
class Country extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Country';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        )
    );

}
?>
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer. But the result was same.
My model files names where wrong. now it's ok